# Lifetime of tokens

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth, oauth-2.0

Does oauth recommend or require request/access tokens to have a specific min/max lifetime? If not, how does one know if the tokens are actually secured?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For OAuth 2 version, access token expiration is strongly recommended.

In [the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-5.1) for access token response, it says:

> expires_in:
>
> RECOMMENDED.  The lifetime in seconds of the access token.  For
> example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will
> expire in one hour from the time the response was generated.
> If omitted, the authorization server SHOULD provide the
> expiration time via other means or document the default value.